# Express JS returns 404 when doing a GET thats more complicated then localhost/users (localhost/users/about)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, get

I have installed the Express framework and used application generator to create the basic app structure.

I am trying to use a separate route file users.js, which was generated by the installer.

I have this code in users.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js contains:

```js
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
```

I do an AJAX call on the /users  (http://localhost/users) and it works
but when I try to do http://localhost/users/about then I get a 404 error:

Error: Not Found
    at ...\app.js:30:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at ...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at ...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
    at next (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

I am new to the framework and just trying to figure what is wrong, thanks.

Comment: Are you hitting the `/users/about` using `post` method ?

Comment: can you post your complete app.js?

Comment: Thanks for answering, the actual problem was that the server has to be rerun each time making a change to one of the files I mentioned in the post. I automated the process by using "nodemon" package: `nodemon npm start`